# A continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb Q$ is constant.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

A continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb Q$ must be constant.

**My Attemps:** Suppose it is not. Then there must be $x,y\in \mathbb R $ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Since $f$ is continuous it achieves all values between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

Later on, I couldn't move. Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are distinct rational numbers. What can be said about the values between them?

Comment: You are almost there. Hint: use the density of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. There is a irrational number between two rational number call it $s$. As I stated beforee, $f$ achieves all values between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ however $s$ is irrational. Impossible.

Comment: The continuous image of a connected set is connected. What are the connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$?